# Angular file input(bootstrap) within ng-repeat does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table which I iterate throurh rows and show information for editing. There I have a file input for image uploading. File input is a bootstrap extension which provides a nice interface. Here is the link : http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo

It has a simple usage you can define your input component using attributs in input tag like data-show-upload or you can use jquery to initialize the component, for example:

```
$("#photo").fileinput({showCaption: false});
```

Here is my table :

```
<table id="table-brand" class="table" style="border-style:none">
<tr>
    <td><b>Marka Adı</b></td>
    <td><b>Bilgi</b></td>
    <td><b>Aktif</b></td>
    <td><b>Logo</b></td>
</tr>
<tr name="brand" ng-repeat="brand in selectedCustomer.brands">
    <td><input name="name" type="text" class="form-control"
           id="field-brand-name"
           style="width:150px" value="" title="Vergi No"/></td>
    <td><textarea name="bio" type="text" class="form-control"
          id="field-brand-bio"
          style="width:150px" value="" title="Vergi No"></textarea></td>
    <td><input index="0" id="photo0" name="photo" type="file" class="file"
           accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" style="width:120px;"
           data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="false"
           data-show-preview="false"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The issue is when I use it with ng-repeat, the file input does not work(The javascript code bind to it doesn't work). When i removed ng-repeat then it works. I guess it's because we need to initialize those inputs using javascript like above because angular creates these elements. So tried the lines :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[name="photo"]').fileinput({showCaption: false, showPreview: false, showUpload: false});
});
```

But it didn't work. Also without deleting ng-repeat, if i take input element outside '< td >' it works.

Thanks.

**Edit :** I debugged the line

```
$(document).ready(function() { .. }
```

and when code execution stops there, angular has not yet rendered the page so query returns nothing and no initializer executes.

I need some function that tells angular to execute after rendering the page or ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       k();
    });


var k= function { $('#photo0').fileinput({showCaption: false, showPreview: false, showUpload: false});}
```

Comment: I tried, actually it's no different from what i mentioned in the question. $(document).ready function executes before angular renders, I need some function executes after angular rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom directive to run the jQuery code. Put the directive on the input field and run the manupilation in the link function of directive.

```
angular.module('moduleName')
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment         
        scope: {
            //@ reads the attribute value, = provides two-way binding, & works with functions
            title: '@'         },
        template: '<div>{{ myVal }}</div>',
        templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
        controller: controllerFunction, //Embed a custom controller in the directive
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) { } //DOM manipulation
    }
});
```

You only need the lunk function from above which gives you the directive element

Comment: Blog to understand how directives work -> http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

Try to create on the controller a function to call the fileinput on the init of the input and pass the input id, like this

```
<input ng-init="myCtrl.init_input_file('your_file_input')" id="your_file_input" type="file">
```

And then creates the function with the fileinput on yout Js

```
$my.init_input_file = function(id){
   $timeout(function(){
      $("#"+id).fileinput();
      $('#'+id).change(function(){
           $my.models.files[id] = this.files;
      });
   });
 };
```

try to create a place to allocate the file inputs on change before you use it.

I solve the problem with the ng-repeat with a timeout without the time, to wait the HTML render.